# How to tell my dev servlet container to use proxy to make http call?

Tags: java, servlets, proxy

I'm behind a firewall,In dev environment I use below during initializing of servlet container(jetty here) but seem not work, even this work in my standalone java command line app:

```
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "xx.xx.xx.xx");
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

Thanks...

Comment: Your web application makes HTTP requests that need to go through the proxy? How did you determine the proxy configuration does not work?

Comment: As I said in title the problem is in dev environment, I have no problem after deployed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add proxy **host port** in jetty configuration file, that will work well.